# how to calculate column to other table

Tags: sql-server, database

i want to make column Customers_Balance on TBL_CUSTOMERS to show by defult the result of that stored procedures....

TBL_CUSTOMERS which it have the info of the customer, and it created as like that

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CUSTOMERS
(
    Customers_ID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    Customers_Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Customers_Phone varchar(100),
    Customers_Address varchar(100),
    Customers_Web varchar(100),
    Customers_Balance decimal(16,0) not null,
);
```

TBL_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS which it have the details of all customer transactions , and it created as like that

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS
(
    Customers_Details_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Customers_ID int,
    Customers_Details_Tybe varchar(50) not null,
    Customers_Details_Date date not null,
    Customers_Details_Amount decimal(16,0) not null,
);
```

i have created stored procedures to calculate the result of sum of customer's transactions balance and worked fine, and it created as like that

```
CREATE PROC SP_SUM_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS_AMOUNT

@ID INT

AS

SELECT SUM(Customers_Details_Amount)

FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS

Where Customers_ID = @ID
```

**NOW**

i want to make column Customers_Balance on TBL_CUSTOMERS to show by defult the result of that stored procedures....

how i can make something like that ??

Comment: There's four major ways to do this. 1) Trigger to update the main table when rows are inserted into the details table.  2) View that calculates the balance when queried, and the column doesn't exist in the main table.  3) Materialized view, which is a little of 1) and 2), and finally 4) Processing job that updates the main table every so often (this option is usually the most problematic, for a number of reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materializing values that can be calculated by other materialize values is usually a bad idea as it bears the risk of inconsistencies.

So you best drop the column `Customers_Balance` in `TBL_CUSTOMERS` and the procedure and then create a view which includes the customer's data and their balance. You can do so by a join and aggregation.

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_CUSTOMERS
            DROP COLUMN Customers_Balance;

DROP PROCEDURE SP_SUM_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS_AMOUNT;

CREATE VIEW VW_CUSTOMERS
AS
SELECT C.Customers_ID,
       C.Customers_Name,
       C.Customers_Phone,
       C.Customers_Address,
       C.Customers_Web,
       sum(CD.Customers_Details_Amount) Customers_Balance
       FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS C
            INNER JOIN TBL_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS CD
                       ON CD.Customers_ID = C.Customers_ID
       GROUP BY C.Customers_ID,
                C.Customers_Name,
                C.Customers_Phone,
                C.Customers_Address,
                C.Customers_Web;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

What you need to do is to create a scalar function rather than a stored procedure (simply change your current stored procedure into a scalar function), and then use this function in your computed column. This would give you an auto-updated results on your computed column.

So, redoing your work should be something like this :

```
-- CREATE THE SCALAR FUNCTION FIRST 
CREATE FUNCTION SUM_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS_AMOUNT (@ID INT)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN (
        SELECT SUM(Customers_Details_Amount)
        FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS
        WHERE Customers_ID = @ID
    )

END
GO

-- NOW DROP THE CURRENT Customers_Balance COLUMN  
ALTER TABLE TBL_CUSTOMERS
DROP COLUMN Customers_Balance
GO
-- CREATE THE COMPUTED COLUMN WITH THE FUNCTION 
ALTER TABLE TBL_CUSTOMERS
ADD Customers_Balance AS dbo.SUM_CUSTOMERS_DETAILS_AMOUNT (Customers_ID)
GO
```